# Aligning a oversized multiple line equation

Tags: align, split

My Apologize, I am new here.
I am noticing my latex is not displaying in a processed format.
How do I do this?

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
\text{max}  & \sum_{k\in K} \sum_{j\in S^k} \pi_{j}x{*{j}^k} &\label{slnl-1} \
\text{such that: } & \pi*{j}   \geq 0,
& \qquad  \forall {j \in J}  \label{slnl-2}  \
\begin{split} \label{slnl-3}
\left( w  s{*{j}^k} + \left(1- w  \right)    \left(r{*{j}^k}- \pi_{j}  \right) \right) x{*{j}^k} \geq {}
&\left( w  s{*{i}^k} + (1- w )   r{*{i}^k}    \right) x{*{j}^k} \
& -  \left( 1- w \right) \pi_{i}  - M  q{_{i}^k},      \qquad \forall {k \in K, i,j \in S^k : i \neq j}
\end{split}  \
% \end{align}
\end{document}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
a = b + c\
d = e + f \qquad g = h + i
\end{gather}
\end{document}

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  What is the question exactly?  To format the code in your question, highlight it with your mouse, then click on the `{}` icon above the question box.

Comment: (La)TeX output isn't automatically shown in this group; in order to answer quetions accurately, we need to look at the input.  This question gives a method to include the output: [How do I get latex output to show up on tex.SE?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4564) (read the comments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the long constraint with `aligned` and also the conditions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
&\text{max}    && \sum_{k\in K} \sum_{j\in S^k} \pi_{j}x_{j}^k \label{slnl-1} \\
&\text{s.t.:} && \pi_{j}   \geq 0, && \qquad  \forall j \in J  \label{slnl-2}  \\
\label{slnl-3}
&&& \begin{aligned}
      & (ws_{j}^k + (1-w )(r_{j}^k - \pi_{j})) x_{j}^k \\
      & \geq (ws_{i}^k + (1-w)r_{i}^k) x_{j}^k - (1-w)\pi_{i} - Mq_{i}^k,
    \end{aligned}
    &&  \quad 
    \left\{\begin{aligned}
    & \forall k \in K, \\
    & \forall i,j \in S^k : i \neq j
    \end{aligned}\right.
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\left(` and `\right)` do no good in this context. Also

```
s{_{j}^k}
```

is wrong syntax and should be, more simply

```
s_{j}^k
```

(or for being consistent, `s_{j}^{k}`).

There is no need of braces after `\forall`, which is not a command with argument.

Finally, “s.t.” used in optimization reads “subject to”, not “such that”.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response , can we use \begin{alignat} for single equations ?

Comment: @DanishShaikh For a single equation use `equation`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
\max    \quad  & \sum_{k\in K} \sum_{j\in S^k} \pi_{j}x{_{j}^k} 
                    &                       \label{slnl-1}  \\
\text{such that:}   % s.t. <?
        \quad  & \pi_{j}   \geq 0,
                    & \forall {j \in J}     \label{slnl-2}  \\
                &   \begin{multlined}       \label{slnl-3}
                \bigl(w s_j^k + (1- w)(r_j^k - \pi_j)\bigr) x_j^k  \geq    \\
                \bigl(w s_i^k + (1- w) r_i^k \bigr) x_j^k - (1-w)\pi_i - Mw_i^k 
                \end{multlined}
                    & \qquad    \forall k \in K;\ \forall  i,j \in S^k : i \neq j
 \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure if I correctly figured out your equations. Anyway a skeleton, how can you organize your optimization problem is given.